# How to represent enum values with space?

Tags: c#, mysql, performance, enums

I have `enums` like the following in my DB:

> "Random Type", "Random Type1", "NewRandom"

Normally, I would represent the values in an enum like:

```
enum myTypes
{
   Random Type = 0,...
}
```

but this is not possible, so I tried using a class

```
static class myTypes
{
    public const string RandomType = "Random Type";
    public const string NewRandom = "NewRandom";
}
```

This way, I can use the class like an `Enum`, but I'm wondering if this is the best implementation possible? Or is there away around creating `Enums` to allow space?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** 
Please, I would also love to know whether there is anything wrong with my current implementation. I have a feeling my current implementation is better than most suggested solutions here.

Thanks

Comment: search for T4 templates....

Comment: Why not call "Random Type" `RandomType` in the Enum instead?

Comment: @Magnus: Because I'm retrieving the `Enum` names.

Comment: Retrieve the keys instead an map using those.

Comment: Can you show me how to do this??

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't do that. Enums are just typesafe `int`s.

There is a solution available, and I quite like it. Use the [DescriptionAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute.aspx).

You'd use it like this:

```
static enum myTypes
{
    [Description("Random Type")]
    RandomType,
    [Descripton("New Random")]
    NewRandom
}
```

and then you'd also need this extension method:

```
public static string GetDescription<T>(this T en) where T : struct, IConvertible
{
    Type type = typeof(T);
    if (!type.IsEnum)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("The type is not an enum");
    }
    MemberInfo[] memInfo = type.GetMember(en.ToString());
    if (memInfo != null && memInfo.Length > 0)
    {
        object[] attrs = memInfo[0].GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
        if (attrs != null && attrs.Length > 0)
        {
            return ((DescriptionAttribute)attrs[0]).Description;
        }
    }
    return en.ToString();
}
```

And then with that, you could just do this:

```
myTypes.RandomType.GetDescription();
```

Answer (score 2):

Enums are much similar to numbers (Integers specifically), rather than strings or so. Adhering to numbered Enums yields you to easy casting, flags-composition (e.g. AND, OR, etc).

I wouldn't use string constant in place of Enums, unless that will bring you more benefits than penalties.

If your goal is to describe to the user the Enum options, I'd suggest to consider to enrich each item with a [Description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.descriptionattribute.aspx) attribute. It's a metadata, rather a real data, but it's also pretty easy to read using reflection.

Cheers

Comment: I am using the Enum names.

Comment: Starting from strings, you should parse them in order to obtain an Enum item. You can't use the "Parse" method of the Enum object, but you may search for the matching description (for-loop or hash-map). That's not worthwhile if you have few options, where a simple switch would be enough.

Answer (score 2):

What I do is I define custom attribute `[DisplayName(string)]` that can be attached to enum values. You define your enum with display name on the values you wish were named with spaces / special characters:

```
public enum Test
{
    None = 0,

    [DisplayName("My Value")]
    MyValue = 1,

    [DisplayName("Spęćiał")]
    Special = 2
}
```

Your implementation in addition to getting enum value name should also check if `DisplayName` attribute is set, and if so, it should take display name instead.

Comment: Explain to me the advantages of this against `[DescriptionAttribute]`?

Comment: @newStackExchangeInstance You control the implementation so it's possible to extend the attribute with more capabilities should you wish to (for example localization support).

Comment: I know you can do that, but for this specific case `DescriptionAttribute` is better.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with display name attributes:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field)]
public class EnumDisplayNameAttribute : DisplayNameAttribute
{
    public EnumDisplayNameAttribute()
        : base(string.Empty)
    {
    }

    public EnumDisplayNameAttribute(string displayName)
        : base(displayName)
    {
    }
}


public static class EnumExtensions
{
    public static string ToDisplayName(this Enum enumValue)
    {
        var builder = new StringBuilder();

        var fields = GetEnumFields(enumValue);

        if (fields[0] != null)
            for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; i++)
            {
                var value = fields[i]
                    .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(EnumDisplayNameAttribute), false)
                    .OfType<EnumDisplayNameAttribute>()
                    .FirstOrDefault();

                builder.Append(value != null
                                   ? value.DisplayName
                                   : enumValue.ToString());

                if (i != fields.Length - 1)
                    builder.Append(", ");
            }

        return builder.ToString();
    }

    private static FieldInfo[] GetEnumFields(Enum enumValue)
    {
        var type = enumValue.GetType();

        return enumValue
            .ToString()
            .Split(new[] { ',', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
            .Select(type.GetField)
            .ToArray();
    }
}
```

usage for type:

```
public enum MyType
{
    [DisplayName("Random Type")]
    RandomType,
    [DisplayName("New Random")]
    NewRandom
}
```

would be:

```
var enumVariable = MyType.RandomType;
var stringRepresentation = enumVariable.ToDisplayName();
```

note that with that approach you would get ToString values if you omit attribute for some enum members.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably **not** use strings as type indicators in your database. Use integers instead. If you like, you can have a "type table" in your database, where you can store the type names, instead of repeating them through the tables that uses them.

If you do this, then you can convert the integers from the database to enums as suggested above.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Typesafe Enum](http://www.javacamp.org/designPattern/enum.html) pattern to achieve your goal.

Idea is to wrap your enum around a class. I guess this is what you want -

```
public class MyTypes
{
    #region Enum Values

    public static MyTypes RandomType = new MyTypes(0, "Random Type");
    public static MyTypes NewRandom = new MyTypes(1, "New Random");

    #endregion

    #region Private members

    private int id;
    private string value;
    private MyTypes(int id, string value)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.value = value;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Overriden members

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return value;
    }

    #endregion

    public static List<MyTypes> GetValues()
    {
        return new List<MyTypes>() { MyTypes.RandomType, MyTypes.NewRandom };
    }
}
```